# django- Quiz app,how to keep track of all user's selected choice

Tags: django

The registered user, selects a answer for a question.

I need to save the selected choice(answer) by each user

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(null = False,max_length= 200)

class Status(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    #red not answered,yellow ans but doubt,answered green
    status = (
        ('Red','Red'),
        ('Yellow','Yellow'),
        ('Green','Green'),
        )
    #Question not answer first so red
    Qstatus = models.CharField(max_length=6,choices=status,default='Red')
    #when user goes to previous question,the selected choice is highlighted 
    selected = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
```

#### When a Question object is created:

How to populate **every user** in Status model,with the newly created question or the the vice-versa

#### Example

I have 5 question.when i am adding a new user the status model should link all questions to the user

#### OR

When a new question is added ,the status model should link all the users with the question

https://github.com/garrykevin-ep/codewars

Comment: Why do you need every user to be in status? This looks like dubious design.

Comment: Can you share the purpose of adding user to every question object

Comment: I need to record the selected choice by each user for each question,So I am linking user and question in status model.So that when the user completes the test,I could check the selected choice to award marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was thinking in the SQL way,not the Django way

when i login a user

```
def s_pop(request):
    current_user = request.user
    qlist = Question.objects.all()
    for x in qlist:
        Status.objects.get_or_create(User = current_user,question = x)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quiz:ans',args = (first_question(),)))
```

Then I redirect to the first question.